# detecting four point of an in image on java fxml

Tags: java, image-processing, fxml, corner-detection, marvin-framework

i am working on an scanner program and i have to detect the four corners of image but as i am beginner in java that is why i am not able to detect it.
i have it by marvin framework but it is giving me some other point rather than the actual point

```
 private Point[] boundaries(MarvinAttributes attr){
    Point upLeft = new Point(-1,-1);
    Point upRight = new Point(-1,-1);
    Point bottomLeft = new Point(-1,-1);
    Point bottomRight = new Point(-1,-1);
    double ulDistance=9999,blDistance=9999,urDistance=9999,brDistance=9999;
    double tempDistance=-1;
    int[][] cornernessMap = (int[][]) attr.get("cornernessMap");
    System.out.println(cornernessMap[0].length);
    for(int x=0; x<cornernessMap.length; x++){
        for(int y=0; y<cornernessMap[0].length; y++){
            if(cornernessMap[x][y] > 0){
                if((tempDistance = Point.distance(x, y, 0, 0)) < ulDistance){
                    upLeft.x = x; upLeft.y = y;
                    ulDistance = tempDistance;
                } 
                if((tempDistance = Point.distance(x, y, cornernessMap.length, 0)) < urDistance){
                    upRight.x = x; upRight.y = y;
                    urDistance = tempDistance;
                }
                if((tempDistance = Point.distance(x, y, 0, cornernessMap[0].length)) < blDistance){
                    bottomLeft.x = x; bottomLeft.y = y;
                    blDistance = tempDistance;
                }
                if((tempDistance = Point.distance(x, y, cornernessMap.length, cornernessMap[0].length)) < brDistance){
                    bottomRight.x = x; bottomRight.y = y;
                    brDistance = tempDistance;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return new Point[]{upLeft, upRight, bottomRight, bottomLeft};
}
 static {
    MarvinDefinitions.setImagePluginPath("D:\\marvin\\marvin\\plugins\\image\\");
}
```

Comment: the four corners of any image are (0,0) (width-1, 0) (0, height - 1) (width - 1, height - 1)  Please read [ask]. It is not clear what you want

Comment: Could you provide the link to the image you are using? So I can run you application using the same image and see what's happening!